# Laravel bootsrap website hacked, how?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Suddenly visiting the terms and conditions from my web I've found this message

```
Ruwix is the best place to learn about the Worlds best selling puzzle toys. Check it out here.
```

Obviously I didn't wrote that down, so I wonder how the heck someone could have added that?

Have someone injected code on my web, or they have access to my ftp? In my computer I use MAC, and I don't think I have any virus.

I've found a lot of websites hacked with the same message but without information about it.

The terms are stored in a blade file.

I had Laravel 5.3 and now 5.5 but I'm unsure when this was done.

Any idea?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the url of your website?

Comment: There are many ways to check for this... Is your TnC stored in DB or Blade file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened to me while ago and I wrote an email to the target email and this was the answer:

You must be using the FREE online HTML editor. Sometimes that adds these ads to your document.
To avoid this I would advise you to purchase a HTML editor license https://htmlg.com/license/

That means that you copy pasted that text from some online editor, no worries, no one has hacked you yet ;)